# Read a JSP servlet page using PHP (libcurl), Python (liburl), or AJAX

Tags: php, python, ajax, jsp, curl

So, I'm attempting to curl a page: `http://rutgers.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TextBookProcessDropdownsCmd?campusId=35577418` in order to extract some data. The issue is that I keep getting either a 404 error or 302 status on the header. I suspect it has something to do with Barnes and Noble's Tomcat not properly redirecting to the servlet when requested remotely. That's just speculation though. I have tried multiple implementations using both libcurl in PHP5, liburl in Python, AJAX (framework and non-framework), and using the curl binary from my terminal.

Here's an example of the output I receive when I echo the response text:

> An error has occurred:
>
> Error Code: 404
>
> Message Target: /BNCB_GenericError.jsp
>
> Servlet Name: JSP 1.2 Processor
>
> Stack Trace: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@14b6c4d
>
> Root Cause: N/A

Here's are the headers I'm sending and receiving:

**Response Headers**

> Expires   Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
>
> Cache-Control no-cache="set-cookie,set-cookie2"
>
> Location  http://uncc.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TBDropDownView?campusId=1748054&dojo.transport=xmlhttp&dojo.preventCache=1300287790307&ddkey=TextBookProcessDropdownsCmd
>
> Content-Length    0
>
> PerfHeader    duration=D=56606,
>
> time=t=1300287776952692
>
> Content-Type  text/html;
>
> charset=ISO-8859-1
>
> Content-Language  en-US Date  Wed, 16
>
> Mar 2011 15:02:57 GMT
>
> Connection    keep-alive
>
> Vary  Accept-Encoding
>
> Set-Cookie    WC_SESSION_ESTABLISHED=true;Domain=.bncollege.com;Path=/
>
> WC_ACTIVESTOREDATA=%2d1%2c0;Domain=.bncollege.com;Path=/WC_USERSESSION_46349649=46349649%2cnull%2cnull%2c%2d2000%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2cnull%2c%5b0%7cnull%7cnull%7cnull%7c%2d2000%5d%2c8XwO3l7WhszbuSO41vmZUDtbpoQ%3d;Domain=.bncollege.com;Path=/
>
> JSESSIONID=0000AuZi2Uo6F6Ft5xihFdUsBQn:app06z02;Domain=.bncollege.com;Path=/
>
> TS884e96=b7fb55c6fcd8aff3987bcdb831a8255a16b4cbcb208252614d80d120;

**Request Headers**

> Host  uncc.bncollege.com
>
> User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U;
>
> Intel Mac OS X 10.6; en-US;
>
> rv:1.9.2.15pre) Gecko/20110227
>
> Firefox/3.6.15pre (Mac Community
>
> Build, ElFurbe)
>
> Accept    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>
> Accept-Language   en-us,en;q=0.5
>
> Accept-Encoding   gzip,deflate
>
> Accept-Charset    ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
>
> Keep-Alive    115 Connection  keep-alive
>
> Referer   http://localhost/bn.php
>
> Origin    http://localhost

And here's the code for that:

```
function bufferURL($url,$bindArgs) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://rutgers.bncollege.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TBWizardView?catalogId=10001&storeId=58552&langId=-1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
    curl_exec($ch);

    $url .= '?';
    foreach ($bindArgs as $a => $b) $url .= $a . '=' . $b . '&';
    $url = substr($url,0,strlen($url)-1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    echo curl_exec($ch);
}
```

BN appears to be using Dojo to perform their AJAX queries to the servlet; however, even when using the same request format, I am unable to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

This looks kind of fishy.  The very first option you set is a URL.  Then you set it to POST data.  Then at the end of the option block, you append a question mark to it, manually append even more query strings, then yank off the extra ampersand... and then re-reset the URL *after* changing it to a GET request!  This makes no sense.

The addition of the question mark is surely at least one of the things that are breaking it -- there's already one in the URL, signifying that it also already has a query string.  Further, you don't seem to be properly URL-encoding any of your additional parameters, so those might also be causing trouble.

Take a look at [`parse_url`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), two tools you can use to disassemble the original URL and retrieve the original query string.  Once you've broken it into components and have extracted the original query string into an array, you can add your new query options to that array / replace existing entries / remove ones you don't want.  You can then use [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to rebuild the query string, and then reassemble the proper URL.

However, that will only really work well if the target accepts this data as a GET instead of as a POST.

If the target requires a POST, you can probably leave the query string alone, and simply submit your query strings as an array, using the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option.  It will do all the hard work for you.

Be advised, it kind of looks like you're trying to use someone's ajax endpoint for unexpected purposes.  It is possible that there are additional protections that they have put in place to deter automated requests.